How to change suggestion popup icons in vscode ？
enter image description here
When I enter console in vscode, these prompts and icons will be displayed。
How can i change the icons shown above ？
Is it easy to customize these icons?
I wish I could customize these icons in some way or use one made by someone else，can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks a lot。
